# make a GET request in node js equivalent to CURL request with -u parameter

Tags: node.js, curl, request

i am trying to make a GET request to an external api from node js and express js.

I am using the request module to make the GET request-

in the options of the request -

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://externalP_api_url/api/1/balance',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
```

I need to set the -u parameter as based on the example in the docs of the api. they used curl to make the request

```
curl -u keyid:keysecret https://externalP_api_url/api/1/balance
```

The problem is i cant set the -u keyid:keysecret in the options of my request i have tried putting it like a query string and in the header but i get a 401 and accoring to the api's docs that means the keyid:keysecret parameter is missing.

I have tried the curl and it works so i knw its not from the api's end and its not cause i am not sending from an https doamain because i would have a gotten a 403 response.

Comment: Could include a link to the api you are trying to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://curl.trillworks.com/#node

It typically does a pretty good job of pointing you in the right direction when converting curl to node.js.  Based on your curl command, it is suggesting the following code:

```js
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://externalP_api_url/api/1/balance',
    auth: {
        'user': 'keyid',
        'pass': 'keysecret'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```